# android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" not working to add admob to bottom

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a admob, 3 textviews and an admob again. This last one I'd like to put on the bottom of my activity. It is now after the last textview. Any ideas what should I change to put admob in the bottom? (not after the last textview)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howTo1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="1) Steep 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howTo2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/howTo1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="2) Steep 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howTo3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/howTo2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="3) Steep 3" />



        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

why alignParentBottom is not working? The admob is after the last textview not in the bottom?

Comment: Try adview out of scrollview. Make relative layout as parent layout.

Comment: @Reena without scrollview it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ad_view"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567">
                </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/howTo1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ad_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="1) Steep 1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/howTo2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/howTo1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="2) Steep 2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/howTo3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/howTo2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="3) Steep 3" />



        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you set height of relative layout to be wrap_content,
you should change it to match_parent, and it will work!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed it, but now I got a warning on xml: this relative should use wrap_content. and it is not in the bottom :(